# MongoDB C#, Persist object which implements IEnumerable

Tags: c#, mongodb, ienumerable

I'm trying to persist objects which use an existing message class to a MongoDB. These objects implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

I have a pretty simple loader implemeneted that works like this:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var database = client.GetDatabase("Test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<AuditMessage>("AuditStream");
var msg = new AuditMessage(payload);
collection.InsertOne(msg);
```

The definition for AuditMessage is something like this:

```
public class AuditMessage : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
```

When I try and persist the messages as it, I get the following error on collection.InsertOne

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException was unhandled
Code=14
ErrorMessage=Wrong type for documents[0]. Expected a object, got a array.
HResult=-2146233088
Message=Command insert failed: Wrong type for documents[0]. Expected a object, got a array..
Source=MongoDB.Driver.Core
```

I confirmed that this was because of the IEnumerable by compiling a version of the message class which didn't implement IEnumerable, this version was able to insert successfully. Unfortunately because a lot of our other products rely on this class I can't just permanently remove the IEnumerable implementation.

Does anyone know of a way to force MongoDB to ignore the IEnumerable implementation, or to otherwise prevent it from trying to treat this object as an array?